# watchguard fb x10 and x15 password reset

Tags: password, watchguard, reset

Is it possible to reset the password on watchguard fb x10 and x15 devices without clearing the config? We have 2 of these devices, they appear to have a serial port but not sure if that provides a console method to reset p/w.

Comment: I highly suspect the answer to this will be - NO, however if you under agreement, contract support.

Comment: You can set a new password by saving a new image to the device, but it doesn't sound like you're in a position to do this. Is it the case that you've lost/forgotten the password?

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation states that you must reset the device to factory settings.  Also, the serial port is for a modem connection, not a console connection.

***User Manual:***

> [User Guide - WatchGuard Technologies](http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/v75FireboxXEdgeUserGuide.pdf%E2%80%8E)